# Physically attach iPad to laptop

Tags: laptop, ipad

Does anyone know of some kind of clamp or other physical attachment that can be used to hold my ipad next to my laptop screen (so I can use it as a second monitor)?

I know how to do it from a softwae point of view. But would like to know the options for the physical attachment

Have googled it extensively but all results are about the software to set it up

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly modify a iPad car cradle to work along side of your laptop. Of course you'll still need a good method of attaching the mount to your laptop, or maybe even a table top.

Comment: I was hoping there might be something that looks like a long hinge (the length of the side of a laptop screen). And each side of the hinge is able to grip. one side grips the side of the laptop, the other the side of the ipad

Comment: They sell various size piano hinges at the hardware store, which would be the type of hinge you describe. That combined with some of the high strength, low adhesive 3M tapes should get you want you want. The tape is really strong, but it doesn't leave any residue behind if you peel it off.